# Bridge Wlan and eth0

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, network-bridge

My problem is the following, I am using a pretty complex network architecture for multi robotic operation. One robot is composed of different embedded computers and a switch, making a local network using the subnet 192.168.88.X.
One of the computers is a raspberry pi, running a Ubuntu 18.4 OS. It uses its antenna to connect to a wireless network, also using the subnet 192.168.88.X.

Here is the situation as a graph :

[Network architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn9QR.png)

My goal is to use the raspberry as a layer 2 bridge, so the two networks act as one extensive network.
I have tried to set the network interfaces, setting the wireless connection as "Shared to other computer", but I still cannot communicate from one computer on the wireless network to the jetson nano linked to the switch on the robot.
I would like if you had any hints?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions.

### Different networks.

1. Set the robot's internal network to a different network address than you use for Wi-Fi.
2. Turn on routing in Raspbery.
3. Set up a static reservation in the DHCP server (probably in the Wi-Fi router) for the Raspberry Wi-Fi interface so that Raspberry always has the same IP address.
4. Set a static route on the (Wi-Fi) network router, which will point to the Wi-Fi address of the robot as the point behind which the internal network of the robot is located.

Raspberry will have two interfaces, each in a different network. Enabling of the routing will allow data to pass through Rasperry. The static path in the Wi-Fi router will help other devices to find and see the internal network of the robot.

### Bridge

Create an L2 bridge between interfaces. Use one of the manuals to do this:

- [Creating a Network Bridge Using NetPlan #1](https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/)
- [Creating a Network Bridge Using NetPlan #2](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-configure-and-use-network-bridge-in-ubuntu-linux/)
- [Identifying the Network Management System and creating bridge](https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/creating-an-ubuntu-kvm-networked-bridge-interface/)

etc.

The correct setting of the bridge is not as simple as it might seem at first glance. Especially for those who do not have experience in creating and setting up network interfaces in different ways.